# Pandas - Adding X number of rows below if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, rows

I have the following dataset:

```
     week_numbs
0.       2
1        4
2.       1
3.       20
4.       3
5.       14
```

I want to check if week_numbs is > 0 and if it is add 'week_numbs' # of empty rows below.
So for the index 0 I would have 2 empty rows below, for index 1 4 empty rows below and so on..

Desired Output :

```
  week_numbs
0.       2
1.
2.
3.       4
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.       1
9.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't understand your second statement ("add 'week_numbs' # of empty rows below"). Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Add the same amount of empty rows as the value corresponding to the week_numbs column. So if week_numbs column is equal to 4 , add 4 empty rows below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
# repeat the rows
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['week_numbs']+1)]
# mask the successive duplicates
df2 = df2.mask(df2['week_numbs'].eq(df2['week_numbs'].shift()), '')
```

output:

```
  week_numbs
0          2
0           
0           
1          4
1           
1           
1           
1           
2          1
2           
3         20
3           
3           
3           
...
```

Comment: This was great, but instead of empty rows I need them to have the same values as the original row from above.

Comment: Then just do the first step, don't mask