# Pandas - Filling empty cells with a string depending one or more column values

Tags: python, pandas, string, rows

Python beginner here and first question on stackoverflow.

I have a dataframe close to that one (omitted some columns)

```
ID Sex Unknown Male Female
1         5     2     1
2         1     0     4
3         3     3     2
```

With the help of this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144017/pandas-adding-x-number-of-rows-below-if-condition-is-met) I was able to get partially what I wanted:
Making X empty rows under each original row depending on the sum of Unknown, Female and Male. I calculated the Sum of Unknown, Male, Female for each row and used that in the code. And later omitted it.

```
ID Sex Unknown Male Female
1         5     2     1







2         1     0     4




3         3     3     2
```

Now I would like to fill in the "Sex" column of the newly created empty rows with corresponding strings to Unknown, Male and Female = "U","M","F" depending on the value of each of those.

Something like that:

```
ID Sex Unknown Male Female
1   U      5     2     1
    U
    U
    U
    U
    M
    M
    F 
2   U      1     0     4 
    F
    F
    F
    F      
3   U      3     3     2
    U
    U
    M
    M
    M
    F
    F
```

And now I am unable to grasp a solution for that Problem. What kind of solutions are there ? Thanks!

Comment: On the second item you have the fill in data on the last item of the set rather than the first.  What rule do you want for where the count data to go?

Comment: I agree with Paul, what should the complete output look like (with values)? Your method of manually adding the rows then filling is likely not the ideal one.

Comment: Made an error in the second dataframe example...edited that.
I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. My last dataframe example is the output I am looking for. The added rows with the U,M,F will be filled later manually for another task where automation is not possible.

Comment: So you just want empty cells except the first row of each group? What is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Yes, I want empty cells except the first row. Except for the 'gender codes' which I want to be autofilled X times in the empty rows, depending on the value of the 'Unknown', 'Male' and 'Female' values.

Comment: My ultimate goal is having a dataframe like in my last example. In my use case further information will be added manually depending on colums not shown here.

Comment: @Claud thanks, I provided an [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843004/16343464)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use `repeat` to repeat your index:

```
# compute the MultiIndex
s = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[0]).stack()
idx = s.repeat(s).to_frame().index

# reshape and set MultiIndex
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.sum(1))].set_axis(idx)

# mask values
m = df2.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()
df2.loc[m] = ''
```

output:

```
Sex   Unknown Male Female
  Sex                    
1 U         5    2      1
  U                      
  U                      
  U                      
  U                      
  M                      
  M                      
  F                      
2 U         1    0      4
  F                      
  F                      
  F                      
  F                      
3 U         3    3      2
  U                      
  U                      
  M                      
  M                      
  M                      
  F                      
  F
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unknown': {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 3},
                   'Male': {1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 3},
                   'Female': {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 2}}).rename_axis(columns='Sex')
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided solution. So far it didn't work for me. When creating the Series "s" it for some reason takes the first Character of the strings of another columns which I did not provide here. There a couple of columns in front of the shown columns in my actual df. Could it be that your code assumes the first columns to be those shown in my/your example df ? Also the Column "Sex" already exists in my actual df, although it is void of entries. I still tried pd.read_excel("dataset.xlsx").rename_axis(columns="Sex") but it didn't seem to help. It works with your provided input, tho. : )

Comment: Yes my code assumes there is no other columns, please update the example if needed (or ask a new question)